# django-gunicorn-nginx: 502 bad gateway

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

I'm trying to ship my web application to the server and this is my first time configuring the server. I'm using **django-gunicorn-nginx** setup by following this tutorial http://ijcdigital.com/blog/django-gunicorn-and-nginx-setup/ First everything was perfect and I got the **django welcome page**. Then I loaded the apps in the django project and setup the static root and Now I'm getting **502 bad gateway** You can check out in http://qlimp.com

Everything upto the gunicorn and supervisor setup is the same as shown in that tutorial. But I modified some nginx conf. Here it is:

```
upstream app_server_djangoapp {
    server localhost:8001 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name qlimp.com;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/guni-access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/guni-error.log info;

    keepalive_timeout 5;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://app_server_djangoapp;
            break;
        }
    }
    location /files/ {
        autoindex on;
        root /home/nirmal/qlimp/qlimp/files/;
    }
}
```

Here is my Media url:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/files/'
```

Files is the folder where I'm having all the static files. How can I get my project to work in the server? Could anyone guide me?

**UPDATE**

Errors.log    https://gist.github.com/2768425

Thanks!

Comment: 502 basically means, that nginx fails to connect to upserver.

Comment: @vartec Why is it so? Have I done any mistake in the conf setup?

Comment: @mk: I have no idea why, you have to debug that yourself. Look at your logs. Try to see if http://localhost:8001 works locally etc.

Comment: debug? could you just tell me the steps?

Comment: @vartec https://gist.github.com/2768425

Comment: [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612829/nginx-serving-django-static-media-502-bad-gateway)

Comment: @Priyank Patel I'm using gunicorn not apache. Could you tell me any similar solution for my setup?

Comment: Before setting up supervisord, make sure it works by just running gunicorn from the command line.

Comment: @rantanplan I tried removing supervisor and run this gunicorn_django --bind=127.0.0.1:8000 It shows this https://gist.github.com/2769593

Comment: @rantanplan guni_error.log https://gist.github.com/2769603

Comment: 1) Give more info on which software versions you run, Linux distro, python, gunicorn, etc. 2) Try binding to 0.0.0.0:8000, 3) Maybe this gets more attention on serverfault.com

Comment: er.. my 2) is invalid in your case so you can ignore it.

Answer (score 13):

First. Don't use `if` in an nginx conf. It's bad. Like really, really horrible. Use the following instead:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri @proxy;
}

location @proxy {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://app_server_djangoapp;
}
```

See: http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil and http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls

Now, as far as debugging goes. Your gunicorn workers are booting because there's some fatal error. Try shutting down gunicorn. If you're using supervisor:

```
sudo supervisorctl stop [gunicorn process name]
```

Then, from your project root run:

```
python manage.py run_gunicorn -c path/to/gunicorn.conf
```

Note any startup errors or if it actually boots, test your site in the browser. If you're still not getting any meaningful info try just running the standard runserver

```
python manage.py runserver
```

Again, note any errors and if it loads fine, test your site in the browser. I suggest testing on localhost:8000 like you would in development. One of these should give you *something* to work with.

**UPDATE**

The error you're getting says it can't connect to "ind=127.0.0.1". Then, looking at the command you're running, `gunicorn_django -bind=127.0.0.1:8001`, it's easy to see the problem. You can specify the IP and port to bind to with either `-b` or `--bind`. Since you only used one `-` it's interpreting the IP as `ind=127.0.0.1`, which is obviously not correct. You need to use:

```
gunicorn_django --bind=127.0.0.1:8001
```

Or

```
gunicorn_django -b 127.0.0.1:8001
```

Comment: I've done modifying as what you told. Then I run this command: `sudo supervisorctl stop qlimp`. It shows  `unix:///var/run/supervisor.sock no such file`

Comment: When I run this `python manage.py runserver` It shows nothing but when I run `gunicorn_django -bind=127.0.0.1:8001` It shows https://gist.github.com/2769983

Comment: And for this code `python manage.py run_gunicorn -c path/to/gunicorn.conf` it shows `Unknown command: 'run_gunicorn'`

Comment: `run_gunicorn` only works if you added gunicorn to `INSTALLED_APPS`. Think I see your problem, though. See update.

Comment: Yes Now I did the changes. Then `python manage.py run_gunicorn -c path/to/gunicorn.conf` It shows https://gist.github.com/2770230 But I Installed python imaging library and It showing the same error again and again

Comment: While I'm installing libjpeg packages as shown here http://thumbnail.sorl.net/requirements.html It shows   Errors were encountered while processing:
 supervisor     E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: That error indicates something went wrong in fetching the package from the repos. It could be a lot of things, but I've seen that error most when there's a signing error, usually as a result of some firewall or content filter interaction. You should open a new question for that on something like superuser.com, though.

Comment: So you think there is no problem in my setup now, is it?

Comment: Not necessarily in your "setup", but your most immediate problem is not being able to install a package from your OS's repo servers. That's more a network issue.

Answer (score 2):

You need to understand directives properly. "server_name" directive holds the IP address and "proxy_pass" will connect to port where your server is hosted. In your case:

```
server_name 127.0.0.1;
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
```

There is no reason for this not to work but still if it does not then try "python manage.py runserver" command to make sure that your site runs with no error because in case site is not able to present data to wsgi.py that likely to show same error.

Answer (score 0):

Increase the keepalive_timeout.

```
server {
        listen 5000 default deferred;
        client_max_body_size 4G;
        keepalive_timeout 5;
        server_name _;
        location / {
            proxy_read_timeout 800;
            proxy_pass  http://localhost:9000;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            break;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a **worker-class** like gevent. 
I had some trouble using gevent in python 3.7, better to use python 3.6.

**Django, Python 3.6 example:**

```
pip install gevent
gunicorn my_app.wsgi --workers 2 --worker-class=gevent --bind 0.0.0.0:80 --timeout=90 --graceful-timeout=10
```

Comment: gevent was a bit behind on support for python 3.7 for a while; the stable release caught up to python 3.7 and 3.8 in gevent 1.5.0.